# Pulling Data into a Gatsby Site Using the WPGraphQL Plugin

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to get wpgraphql to work with Gatsby (per the instructions in this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH7I1xRrbxs).

In my `gatsby-config` file, I have set up the `gatsby-source-graphql` plugin as follows

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
  options: {
    typeName: 'WORDPRESS',
    fieldName: 'wordpress',
    url: 'URL_GOES_HERE',
    refetchInterval: 60,
  },
},
```

Now, if I use the following URL (which is for demo purposes), then everything works just fine:  https://api.wpgraphql.com/graphql

However, if I use the following URL then it does NOT work: https://wordpress-285784-933130.cloudwaysapps.com/graphql

That second URL is from my Wordpress install -- and as far as I know everything is set up just fine on my wordpress site.  I have the following Plugins installed:

- wpgraphql
- wpgraphiql
- WPGraphQL Custom Post Type UI
- WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields
- Custom Post Type UI
- Advanced Custom Fields

And I have made sure that Custom Post Type UI and Advanced Custom Fields are set up to work with wpgraphql.  And, indeed, I can make graphql queries on that site using the wpgraphiql plugin.  That is, on that site everything works as it is supposed to.

And yet, it doesn't work in terms of being able to pull that data into my gatsby install.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I tried calling different graphQL queries like

```
https://wordpress-285784-933130.cloudwaysapps.com/graphql?query={%20page{id}%20}
```

which gives errors stating missing mandatory data which seems to be a problem with your data. Also it will be useful if you can check if the query you are trying to call is actually giving results directly as shown above which you mentioned does work in **wpgraphiql**.

Comment: Those errors are expected -- as noted in the documentation for wpgraphql:  https://docs.wpgraphql.com/getting-started/install-and-activate (scroll to 'Verify the Endpoints Work').  [and in case you are wondering, I DO have pretty permalinks enabled].

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [`gatsby-source-wordpress`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/). That will import all data provided in your config and convert it to GraphQL.

If you're interested in this, you can follow the tutorial of [Tim Smith](https://www.iamtimsmith.com/blog/how-to-build-a-blog-with-wordpress-and-gatsby-part-1/)

Hope that it helps you!

Comment: The gatsby-source-wordpress plugin uses the Wordpress Rest API and does NOT work with the wpgraphql plugin.  It is, of course, an option -- but I would like to get this to work using the wpgraphql plugin if I can.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not have SSL set up on my domain and I was using an `https`.  I switched the URL to `http` and everything worked fine.

NOTE:  A Special thanks to Jason Bahl (the wpgraphql plugin creator) who went the extra mile and figured this out.